# Django Queryset - extracting only date from datetime field in query (inside .value() )

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I want to extract some particular columns from django query

models.py

```
class table
  id = models.IntegerField(primaryKey= True)
  date = models.DatetimeField()
  address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  city = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  cityid = models.IntegerField(20)
```

This is what I am currently using for my query

```
obj = table.objects.filter(date__range(start,end)).values('id','date','address','city','date').annotate(count= Count('cityid')).order_by('date','-count')
```

I am hoping to have a SQL query that is similar to this

```
 select DATE(date), id,address,city, COUNT(cityid) as count from table where date between "start" and "end" group by DATE(date), address,id, city order by DATE(date) ASC,count DESC;
```

Answer (score 26):

At least in Django 1.10.5, you can use something like this, without `extra` and `RawSQL`:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Cast
from django.db.models.fields import DateField
table.objects.annotate(date_only=Cast('date', DateField()))
```

And for filtering, you can use `date` lookup (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#date):

```
table.objects.filter(date__date__range=(start, end))
```

Comment: That is really nice ! I've tried to use it without keyword argument, which is possible with simple expressions like `annotate(Min('date'))`,..but with this Cast, the keyword-alias is mandatory.

Comment: with Oracle I had to do `from django.db.models.functions import Trunc` and `table.objects.annotate(date_only=Trunc('date', 'day', output_field=DateField()))`

Answer (score 6):

For the below case.

```
select DATE(date), id,address,city, COUNT(cityid) as count from table where date between "start" and "end" group by DATE(date), address,id, city order by DATE(date) ASC,count DESC;
```

You can use [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) where you can implement DB functions.

```
Table.objects.filter(date__range(start,end)).extra(select={'date':'DATE(date)','count':'COUNT(cityid)'}).values('date','id','address_city').order_by('date')
```

Hope it will help you.

Thanks.

Comment: Nowadays, [`.extra` should only be used as a last resort](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra).  Is there any alternative?

Comment: I think they have mentioned its equivalent on in the above mentioned docs, As they said you should use RawSQL (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.expressions.RawSQL).